# XNA `tex2Dlod` always returns transparent black

Tags: xna, shaders, hlsl

I want to sample a texture in a vertex shader, so at first I just tried using

```
float2 texcoords = ...;
color = tex2D(texture, texcoords);
```

But apparently I cannot use `tex2D` in a vertex shader, and must use `tex2Dlod`. So then I changed the above code to

```
color = tex2Dlod(texture, float4(texcoords, 0, 0));
```

But now `color` is always `float4(0, 0, 0, 0)` (i.e. transparent black).

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I know for a fact that the texture does not contain just transparent black pixels.

Comment: How do you set the texture and are you sure it has LOD information?

Comment: I set the texture by using `GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = texture;` (using `0` as an example) and then `sampler texture = register(s0);` in the shader. How can I determine if the texture has LOD information?